# Whole house surge protection

Tags: electrical

Can I share a 240 whole house surge protector breaker with my dryer.My panel is 100amps and has no room left

Comment: A picture of your panel with the labels might help.  I doubt very much that you can combine the two/or switch, but there might be ways to free up two spots in your panel.

Comment: Make/model # of panel of surge protector should provide the answer. Some are designed to share a breaker, but not necessarily all of them.

Answer (score 1):

By sharing I assume you mean connecting the whole house surge protector to the 30 A 2-pole dryer breaker, right? I think you can do this, although technically this might be a misuse if the breaker is specified for one wire only on each pole.

Presumably if the dryer was on when a surge occured, then the surge protector *might* not have its full range of protection available, but this should still provide some protection. Also if the surge protector would develop a fault and you wanted to disconnect it, then you would have to flip off the dryer circuit or remove the front of the panel to pull the surge protector leads out of the breaker. But if your panel has no open slots, it seems to me that it would be reasonable to connect it through the dryer breaker.

For a time I had my whole house surge protector connected to the 50 A 2-pole breaker for the ciruit to the electric range and it worked just fine. I later put in a 50 A breaker just for the surge protector, but I wonder if that was really necessary.

The stranded wire leads on the surge protector would have to be placed in the breaker so that the clamping face would make a good connection.